# infimum of the upper closure of certain set coincides with the infimum of this set.

Tags: real-analysis

$(DEF):$ Let $X$ be a totally ordered set. A set $A \subset X$ is called an upper set if $a \in A $ and $x > a $ implies $x \in A $.

Also, the least upper set that contains $A$ is called the upper closure of $A$.

$(PROBLEM)$: Let $X$ be totally ordered set and $A \subset X$. Say $B$ is the upper closure of $A$. Then $\inf B $ exists iff $\inf A$ exists and $\inf A = \inf B $.

#### Attempt:

Say $\inf B = \beta$ exists. We know $A \subset B $. Let $x \in  A $ be arbitrary. Then $x \in B$. We have $x \geq \beta$ and so $\beta$ is a lower bound for $A$, in particular $\inf A$ exists and $\inf A \geq \beta $. I am stuck here since I dont know how to show $\inf A \leq \beta$.

As for the other direction, I am puzzled since it doesnt make sense to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve shown that $A$ has a lower bound, but that’s not enough to show that $\inf A$ exists. For instance, $\{q\in\Bbb Q:q>0\text{ and }q^2>2\}$ is bounded below by $0$, but it has in infimum in $\Bbb Q$.

The easiest way to show that $\inf A$ exists is to show that it’s $\beta$. Suppose that $x$ is a lower bound for $A$. Then $[x,\to)$ is an upper set containing $A$, so $[x,\to)\supseteq B$, and therefore $x\le\beta=\inf B$. (If $x$ were greater than $\beta$, there would be some $b\in B$ such that $b<x$ and hence $b\in B\setminus[x,\to)=\varnothing$, which is absurd.) You've already shown that $\beta$ is a lower bound for $A$, so it is the greatest lower bound for $A$; in other words, $\beta=\inf A$, which of course therefore exists.

In the other direction you’re trying to show that if $B$ is the upper closure of $A$, and $\inf A$ exists, then $\inf B$ exists and is equal to $\inf A$. To give you a chance to do it yourself, I’ll limit myself for now to a hint: show that if $\alpha=\inf A$, then $B$ is either $(\alpha,\to)$ or $[\alpha,\to)$.

(Notation: $(x,\to)=\{y\in X:x<y\}$, and $[x,\to)=\{y\in X:x\le y\}$.)

Comment: your arrow $\rightarrow$ means $\infty$ ? and thanks your response Prof. Scott

Comment: @Willie: You’re welcome. Yes, I prefer the arrow notation for rays in linear orders: $(\leftarrow,a)=\{x\in X:x<a\}$ and so on. The $\infty$ notation makes it look a bit as if there were actually something there at the end of the order; the arrow seems more intuitive. But both notations are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: why is $[x, \rightarrow)$ an upper set containing $A$ ?

Comment: @Willie: If $x$ is a lower bound for $A$, then $x\le a$ for each $a\in A$, so $A\subseteq[x,\to)$. (And $[x,\to)$ is certainly an upper set.)

Comment: but B is the least upper set containing A. shouldnt it $B \subset [x, \rightarrow)$?

Comment: @Willie: Yes: I typed subseteq instead of supseteq. I've fixed that and improved the write-up a bit as well, I think. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thank you Prof. Scott. I am kind of stuck trying to show $B$ is either one of $( \alpha, \rightarrow )$ or $[\alpha, \rightarrow)$ ? can you provide with more hints?

Comment: @Willie: $[\alpha,\to)$ is an upper set containing $A$, so we know that $B\subseteq[\alpha,\to)$. Now show that $\bigcup_{a \in A}[a,\to)$ is the smallest upper set containing $A$ and that it's equal to $[\alpha,\to)$ or to $(\alpha,\to)$ depending on whether $\alpha$ is in $A$ or not.

Comment: I am stuck on the converse. Can you give me some further hints: This is what I got so far: Suppose $\alpha = \inf A$ exists. $B$ is upward closure of $A$. Want: $\inf B = \alpha$. Ww know $[ \alpha, \infty) $ is an upper set and hence $B \subset [ \alpha, \infty) $. IT follows that $\alpha \leq b$ and so $\alpha $ is a lower bound of $B$. Here is where I am stuck. I already have $\alpha $ is an upper bound. What should I use to show it is indeed the supremum ?

Comment: @Willie: I think that you mean that it’s a lower bound, and you still need to show that it’s the infimum. If $\alpha\in A$, then $\alpha$ is actually the smallest member of $A$, so it’s also the smallest member of $B$. If a set has a minimum, that minimum is necessarily its infimum, so in this case $\alpha=\inf B$. The other possibility is that even though $\alpha=\inf A$, it’s not actually in $A$. In this case you can show that for each $x>\alpha$ there is a $b\in B$ such that $\alpha<b<x$.